# Function in C# to call a class/method as in php

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm taking my first steps in c # & asp.net and I'm enjoying it much.
Now, I have a question...
Is there a function in C# to call a class/method as in php?
For example:

```
$class = array(
    "foo", // class name
    "bar" // method name
);
$params = array(
    "one",
    "two"
);
call_user_func_array($class, $params); //execute Foo->bar("one","two");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, there is nothing built in to do exactly that. You could build a method that does something similar using reflection, but it seems like a solution looking for a problem.

```
void Main()
{
    CallUserFuncArray("UserQuery+Foo", "Bar", "One", "Two");
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Foo
{
    public static void Bar(string a, string b){}
}

public void CallUserFuncArray(string className, string methodName, params object[] args)
{
    Type.GetType(className).GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(null, args);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this on non-static methods?

Comment: @TechplexEngineer: Yes. Instead of passing `null` into the Invoke method, pass the instance of the object you want to call the method on. But honestly, why would you do this?

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, there are multiple ways to simulate this, but no "baked-in" functionality in C#. The most flexible way is with reflection, but you can do it in a much simpler (and easier to deal with) way if you know the list of methods you'll be calling beforehand.

```
class Foo
{
    public static string FooA(int p1, int p2) 
    { 
        return "FooA:" + p1 + p2; 
    }
    public static string FooB(int p1, int p2) { return "FooB:" + p1 + p2; }
    public static string FooC(int p1, int p2) { return "FooC:" + p1 + p2; }
}    
class Bar
{
    //You can use Func<int, int, object> instead of a delegate type,
    //but this way is a little easier to read.
    public delegate string Del(int p1, int p2);

    public static string DoStuff()
    {        
        var classes = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Del>>();
        classes.Add("Foo", new Dictionary<string, Del>());
        classes["Foo"].Add("FooA", Foo.FooA);
        classes["Foo"].Add("FooB", Foo.FooB);
        classes["Foo"].Add("FooC", Foo.FooC);

        //...snip...

        return classes["Foo"]["FooA"](5, 7);
    }
}
```

[Which, by the way, does work.](http://rextester.com/SUD66091)

If you *don't* know which methods you want to make available this way, I suggest you reconsider whaever you're trying to do. The only reason I can think of for using strings to choose your execution path would be if you were planning to get those strings from the user. Not only is it a huge no-no to expose inner details of your application like this, but it comes dangerously close to `eval`-type functionality. There's a reason C# doesn't have an `eval` method, and it isn't because the designers forgot to put it in.

Answer (score 1):

As @StriplingWarrior said, there's no built-in equivalent of `call_user_func_array`, but you can do something like it with Reflection.

The problem is that Reflection code can get very complicated very quickly, and can be brittle and error-prone if you're not VERY careful.

For example the following function does what you want:

```
public static void CallUserFuncArray(string[] func, params string[] args)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(func[0]);
    if (type == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The specified Class could not be found");
    }

    var method = type.GetMethod(func[1], BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
    if (method== null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The specified Method could not be found");
    }

    method.Invoke(null, args);
}
```

You call it like this:

```
var func = new [] { "Foo", "Bar" };
var args = new [] { "one", "two" };

CallUserFuncArray(func, args);
```

The problems though are many.

- The code only works if `Bar` is a public static method.
- There's a whole new layer of complexity if you need to call an instance method on an object.
- The code will explode if the parameters in the `args` array aren't just right for the target method.
- There's no support here for calling methods that expect anything other than string parameters.  It's possible to query the type of the arguments expected by the method and convert the types before calling 'Invoke', but you're getting even more messy.
- There are many more edge cases that blow out the complexity of this code even more if you need to cater for them.

To paraphrase Carl Franklin (of dotNetRocks fame):

> I had a problem I needed to solve, so I used Reflection. Now I have two problems.

I you find yourself need to do this sort of thing thenyou probably need to rethink your overall design.